# parsename on longer string

Tags: sql, split, sql-server-2016

Hi i am trying to split a value from a long text using parsename and replace (WITHIN A SELECT)

it works fine for the last 2 strings but does not for the first. The only reason i can see is its not working with longer string

> PK-Practice Manager ID:34926,PracticeManagerName:Old--New-Julie Abdilla|Is Delegate:Old--New-True|Enable Practice Access Portfolio:Old--New-True|EnableRemittanceAdviceAuthority:Old--New-True|
>
> PK-Practice Manager ID:38864,EnableRemittanceAdviceAuthority:Old-False-New-True|
>
> PK-Practice Manager ID:38691,Is Delegate:Old--New-False|Enable Practice Access Portfolio:Old--New-False|EnableRemittanceAdviceAuthority:Old--New-True|

i want to split it on ',' and use the first part of string only

so i do

```
select parsename(replace(@text, ',', '.'), 2)
```

The first string returns null while others return the correct value

Comment: which database?

Answer (score 0):

Since i was not bothered about the second part of split, so I just did

```
parsename(replace(substring(@text, 0, 157), ',', '.'),2)
```

I checked it manually, so any character I added after index 157 would start returning null therefore I guess this was the limit for parsename